Issue with sources.list in ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal
When I try to update my libraries and packages with the command apt update it show the error with Failed to fatch ... "source.list" issue.

Unless you provide the specific output you see (and ideally with the command that generated that output) we're limited in what help we can provide.

@guiverc The OP reported in his self-answer: "I found the solution: I checked and found that for some reason I lost my eth0 interface."

I found the solution. I checked and found that for some reason I lost my eth0 interface. This was the issue which was related with the sources.list I mentioned.
To bring back the eth0 I followed these steps to create a configuration file in /etc/systemd/network as follows:
# vim /etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network

Inside the file I added the following configuration:
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

After this configuration I restarted the service:
# systemctl restart systemd-networkd

